# VideoJS in reactJS with google IMA plugin

Tags: reactjs, video.js, google-ima

We're migrating to VideoJS in ReactJS project, everything seems to work fine except for google IMA plugin.

Are there any resources on how to use google-ima plugin in React? 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-ima-player

I'm getting 'Uncaught Error: plugin "ima" does not exist' error here

```
import React from "react";
import videojs from 'video.js'
import 'videojs-ima';

class VideoJS extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(this.props)
    }


    generetePlayerOptions = () => {
        return (
            {
                autoplay: true,
                controls: true,
                language: 'lt',
                poster: this.props.playlist[0].image,
                aspectRatio: '16:9',
                sources: [{
                    src: this.props.playlist[0].file,
                    type: 'video/mp4'
                }],
                plugins: {
                    ima: {
                        adTagUrl: 'http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/ad_rule_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&ad_rule=1&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vmap1&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=sample_ar%3Dpremidpostpod%26deployment%3Dgmf-js&cmsid=496&vid=short_onecue&correlator='
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // instantiate Video.js
        this.player = videojs(this.videoNode, this.generetePlayerOptions(), function onPlayerReady() {
            console.log('onPlayerReady', this)
        })
    }
```

Comment: By the way, if I try to call this.player.ima() i get "ima is not a function" as well.

Comment: Are you using official plugin or that you linked? Does both throw this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it won't work if you import it.
I don't like too much what i did but it works.

1. Need to add the scripts/css on the head of index.html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/dist/videojs.ima.css" />

<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="//imasdk.googleapis.com/js/sdkloader/ima3.js"></script>
<script src="//googleads.github.io/videojs-ima/node_modules/videojs-contrib-ads/dist/videojs.ads.min.js"></script>
<script src="videojs.ima.js"></script>
```

2. Now you can get the player with "window.videojs()" and add the ima plugin with the options. Something like this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
    var player = window.videojs('content_video', {}, function () {
      var options = {
        id: 'content_video',
        adTagUrl: 'https://pubads.g.doubleclick.....'
      };
      player.ima(options)
    });
    player.ready(function () {
      player.play() //start on load
    })
    
  }
```

3. In the render function you just have to define the id for the video tag (same as the one on ComponentDidMount)
4. The ad won't start if there is no source for the player.

Comment: Tried this approach in Next.js, added the above link tags in custom _document.js, however, getting player.ima is not a function